# Can't x:Bind to global ObservableCollection<Type>

Tags: c#, data-binding, winrt-xaml, win-universal-app, xbind

I used Jerry's technique:

[App-wide Observable Collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14937563/app-wide-observable-collection/35367205?noredirect=1#comment58443543_35367205)

and got a compilation error CS0176 with the message:

Member 'Page.Items' cannot be accessed with an instance reference; qualify it with a type name instead.

I am trying to x:Bind to an ObservableCollection Items.

Anyone knows how to fix this error.

thanks

Answer (score 2):

So, I just double-checked, this time with `x:bind`.

This is the code:

```
public class x
{
    public static ObservableCollection<string> Items { get; } = new ObservableCollection<string>();
}

public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public ObservableCollection<string> Items { get { return x.Items; } }
}
```

And this is the XAML:

```
<!--  page content  -->
<StackPanel Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Orientation="Horizontal"
            Padding="12,8,0,0">

    <ListView ItemsSource="{x:Bind Items}" />

</StackPanel>
```

Works like a charm. Looks like this:

[image]

So, I am not sure why you are seeing this error. But, to your question, there is no fix because this works. If you figure out the problem you were getting be sure and follow-up with a comment. Otherwise, best of luck!

Comment: Thanks Jerry it worked, I was missing the { get; } when defining the ObservableCollection<t> Items.